# Can Google Chrome Canary be reverted to previous version?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chrome-canary

I utilize **Google Chrome Canary** for development work.

**System**:
OS: macOS Big Sur 11.2.3
**Processor**: i7

Since Canary has a [nightly build](https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/), I am regularly running `Update Chrome` button in the browser, but not every day. Yesterday, this update caused Canary to crash. I tried the following:

- Restarting Canary
- Downloading and re-installing the Canary build
- Restarting my computer

None worked. Today, I simply re-downloaded the nightly build, and *voila* all was working again.

*(Working Build: Version 92.0.4476.0 (Official Build) canary (x86_64))*

On the above link, they fully warn ye who enter here:

> Get on the bleeding edge of the web. Be warned: Canary can be unstable.

So I guess I'll treat this, my first question, as practice if there really is no good answer:

**Is there anywhere safe on the web to download and run a previous version of the Canary build in these situations?** Otherwise I might just have to save my last stable download locally and have that as a fall-back.

Answer (score 0):

You could find and backup the last build of your canary in these default folder:

```
For macOS:
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome Canary/

For windows 10:
\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application
```

I'm not sure if you could find the previous build in there.